# Makefile should search for .o files in another directory

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, linker, autoconf

So I am using autoconf to generate a Makefile, and I've been successful in doing so and compiling my project, but the problem is that the object files are created in the `src` folder. I want them to be compiled in the `.libs` folder.

I am able to do that as well, but then another problem arises, the compiler searches for these `.o` files in the same folder as the `.cpp` files (which is `src`).

I have tried everything including:

```
%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ -c $<
```

and

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

and so many other combinations that I don't even remember.
For some reason, these rules don't end up looking for the object files in the `.libs` folder, and I get errors while running make:

```
g++: error: One.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: Two.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: Three.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: Four.o: No such file or directory
```

This is my Makefile.am, so far:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -I/chome/siddhs/soft/soft_source_code/target/src/include/ -I/home/siddhs/EclipseProjects/rdma2/include
AM_LDFLAGS=-L /usr/pbs/new/exec/lib/ -lsoft -lpthread -llmx-altair -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lcrypto -L . -lsoft

OUT=rdma2.a
CC=g++
OBJDIR=/home/siddhs/EclipseProjects/rdma2/.libs
SDIR=/home/siddhs/EclipseProjects/rdma2/src
INC=-Iinc
ADIR=/usr/local/rdma2/

bin_PROGRAMS=rdma2test

rdma2test_SOURCES = One.cpp Two.cpp Three.cpp Four.cpp
rdma2test_LDADD=-L /usr/soft/new/exec/lib -lsoft -lpthread -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lcrypto

_OBJS = One.o Two.o Three.o Four.o

%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: You show us the `Makefile.am`, but where is the makefile that uses it, the one with the rule for actually building something out of these object files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a second `Makefile.am` inside the `.libs` directory. The top `Makefile.am` will need only to point in the second `Makefile.am`. The second will describe all the build process.

A simple example will contain the the following.

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = .libs
```

**.libs/Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS=rdma2test
noinst_LIBRARIES= librdma2.a
AM_LDFLAGS=-L.
librdma2_a_SOURCES = $(SRC)/One.cpp $(SRC)/Two.cpp
rdma2test_SOURCES = $(SRC)/Main.cpp
rdma2test_LDADD= -lrdma2
```

**configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([rdma2],[1.0])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/Main.cpp])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CXX(g++)
AC_PROG_RANLIB
SRC=`pwd`"/src"
AC_SUBST(SRC)
AC_OUTPUT([Makefile .libs/Makefile])
```

**Note:** With this configuration later versions of `automake` issue a warning message.